# Html how to make H1, H2, etc as links?

Tags: html

What is the correct code for turning a h1, h2 etc heading into a link and `search engines` index texts of header and link both?

Is it:

```
<a href="#"><h1>heading</h1></a>
```

or

```
<h1><a href="#">heading</a></h1>
```

and could anyone explain why ?

Comment: Your second example would be preferred.

Comment: thanks and why is that so ?

Comment: As of HTML5 both are valid.

Comment: @Omid 2nd option is best than 1st because it has a logical hierarchy. It makes more sense to include a link inside another element such as a title over leaving the link outside of the title.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Per here: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.4

`%flow` element which display as a block (in this case `<h1>`) always should surround `%inline` elements (such as `<a>`).

Another example `<div>` should *always* be outside `<span>`.

That is to say:

```
<h1><a href="#">heading</a></h1>
```

is correct.

---

An even easier way of under standing this is that the following makes sense:

```
<h1><a href="#1">my link</a> and <a href="#2">my other link</a></h1>
```

It would be highly unusual to try the inverse with multiple `<h1>`s inside an `<a>`.

Comment: what about seo? what's the output of `<h1><a href="#">heading</a></h1>` ? an empty text for seo or **heading** ?

Comment: All major crawlers are intelligent enough to respect a <h1> tag. Providing your anchor tag is not malicious or erroneous. Basically I don't have any idea what you're asking here.

Comment: @RobertJ. What seo doing about a heading like `<h1><a href="#1">my link</a> and <a href="#2">my other link</a></h1>` ?

Comment: @812621 I'm not a SEO expert but I imagine it would depend on which attributes you put on the anchor tags, ie href and title. I imagine the `<h1>` would be interpreted per normal and where it is in the DOM matters more than its internal inline elements.

Answer (score 0):

If You go with code1

```
<a href="#"><h1>heading</h1></a>
```

you are just able to make it as a link with highlight feature.
But If you go with code2

```
<h1><a href="#">heading</a></h1>
```

you will probably able to satisfy some css property as h1 a{ //hover or text decoration}

I will go with second code. ... Both will work.