# how to add a href to a text on top of a

Tags: html

I have a text which appears on top of an image:

```html
<h2 class="w3-hide-large" style="white-space:nowrap">sitename</h2>
```

and want to add a `href="/"` to the text. I have tried both approaches from [the answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20174426/html-how-to-make-h1-h2-etc-as-links) as for example:

```html
<a href="/">
  <h2 class="w3-hide-large" style="white-space:nowrap">sitename</h2>
</a>
```

but in either case, the text disappears behind the image. What must be changed to have the text as a reference on top as it shows without the `href`?

Comment: What does your css look like? You won't get this with just HTML. And if you need it to be clickable you could just add js to if, unless you need the anchor for something.

Comment: What image? Nothing in the code you've shared will show an image. Please read [ask], in particular the part about providing a [mcve].

Comment: i guess the css now needs to be applied to the <a> element, not the <h2>, since you wrapped your <h2> into a <a> element

Comment: Also you can put the a into the h2 : `<h2><a>test</a></h2>` if you prefer, it's still a valid syntax